# Partition a zigzag-shaped time series

Tags: time-series

I have a time series that zigzags up and down in cycles. I want to find a simple algorithm to partition it into segments of up sequences and down sequences.

It should be robust to noise so that a small kink shouldn't partition a sequence needlessly. Is there a name for such a technique?

**EDIT**: several of you have brought up seasonality. This is something I'm not literated in. Surely its something for me to learn. In this case I'm only want to find the points when direction change. I'm not sure if there considered any seasonality, in the sense of regular recurrence, in the data.

Comment: How is what you're asking about different from assessing seasonality (which I believe is standard in time-series analysis)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function borrowed from the TA community, called a ZigZag indicator (which can be adjusted for noise thresholds). It is available in the TTR package of R.

[image: zigzag]

[zigzagR](http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=TTR:ZigZag)

It might be possible to do the transformation(s) using classical time-series decomposition methods, but I don't know of a simple way to adjust the noise thresholding as in the zig-zag function.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I downloaded the package and it leads me to some Fortran source code! Lol now I need to understand it and reimplement in Python.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Peter's suggestion of testing for seasonality, it would be useful to test for markov regime-switching properties in both the mean and variance of the time series, especially if you are working with economic or financial data.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Fourier transform of the time series to determine its frequency and phase shift, then use that segment the series into periods of increase and decrease.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Usually answers, as opposed to comments, provide more fully worked out solutions, but I think this qualifies as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Is seasonal decomposition what you are looking for.  This breaks down a time series into its trend, seasonal, and irregular or random components.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an already created zigzag indicator coded in Python working with Pandas [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ZigZag/0.1). Code from the author:

```python
import numpy as np

# Numba can be a pain to install. If you do not have numba, the functions 
# will be left in their original, uncompiled form. 
try:
    from numba import jit
except ImportError:
    def jit(_):
        def _f(f):
            return f 
        return _f

PEAK, VALLEY = 1, -1


@jit('i8(f8[:],f8,f8)')
def _identify_initial_pivot(X, up_thresh, down_thresh):
    """Quickly identify the X[0] as a peak or valley."""
    x_0 = X[0]
    max_x = x_0
    max_t = 0
    min_x = x_0
    min_t = 0
    up_thresh += 1
    down_thresh += 1

    for t in range(1, len(X)):
        x_t = X[t]

        if x_t / min_x >= up_thresh:
            return VALLEY if min_t == 0 else PEAK

        if x_t / max_x <= down_thresh:
            return PEAK if max_t == 0 else VALLEY

        if x_t > max_x:
            max_x = x_t
            max_t = t

        if x_t < min_x:
            min_x = x_t
            min_t = t

    t_n = len(X)-1
    return VALLEY if x_0 < X[t_n] else PEAK


@jit('i1[:](f8[:],f8,f8)')
def peak_valley_pivots(X, up_thresh, down_thresh):
    """
    Finds the peaks and valleys of a series.
    Parameters
    ----------
    X : This is your series.
    up_thresh : The minimum relative change necessary to define a peak.
    down_thesh : The minimum relative change necessary to define a valley.
    Returns
    -------
    an array with 0 indicating no pivot and -1 and 1 indicating valley and peak
    respectively
    Using Pandas
    ------------
    For the most part, X may be a pandas series. However, the index must
    either be [0,n) or a DateTimeIndex. Why? This function does X[t] to access
    each element where t is in [0,n).
    The First and Last Elements
    ---------------------------
    The first and last elements are guaranteed to be annotated as peak or
    valley even if the segments formed do not have the necessary relative
    changes. This is a tradeoff between technical correctness and the
    propensity to make mistakes in data analysis. The possible mistake is
    ignoring data outside the fully realized segments, which may bias analysis.
    """
    if down_thresh > 0:
        raise ValueError('The down_thresh must be negative.')

    initial_pivot = _identify_initial_pivot(X, up_thresh, down_thresh)

    t_n = len(X)
    pivots = np.zeros(t_n, dtype='i1')
    pivots[0] = initial_pivot

    # Adding one to the relative change thresholds saves operations. Instead
    # of computing relative change at each point as x_j / x_i - 1, it is
    # computed as x_j / x_1. Then, this value is compared to the threshold + 1.
    # This saves (t_n - 1) subtractions.
    up_thresh += 1
    down_thresh += 1

    trend = -initial_pivot
    last_pivot_t = 0
    last_pivot_x = X[0]
    for t in range(1, len(X)):
        x = X[t]
        r = x / last_pivot_x

        if trend == -1:
            if r >= up_thresh:
                pivots[last_pivot_t] = trend
                trend = 1
                last_pivot_x = x
                last_pivot_t = t
            elif x < last_pivot_x:
                last_pivot_x = x
                last_pivot_t = t
        else:
            if r <= down_thresh:
                pivots[last_pivot_t] = trend
                trend = -1
                last_pivot_x = x
                last_pivot_t = t
            elif x > last_pivot_x:
                last_pivot_x = x
                last_pivot_t = t

    if last_pivot_t == t_n-1:
        pivots[last_pivot_t] = trend
    elif pivots[t_n-1] == 0:
        pivots[t_n-1] = -trend

    return pivots


def compute_segment_returns(X, pivots):
    """Return a numpy array of the pivot-to-pivot returns for each segment."""
    pivot_points = X[pivots != 0]
    return pivot_points[1:] / pivot_points[:-1] - 1.0


@jit('f8(f8[:])')
def max_drawdown(X):
    """
    Return the absolute value of the maximum drawdown of sequence X.
    Note
    ----
    If the sequence is strictly increasing, 0 is returned.
    """
    mdd = 0
    peak = X[0]
    for x in X:
        if x > peak: 
            peak = x
        dd = (peak - x) / peak
        if dd > mdd:
            mdd = dd
    return mdd


@jit('i1[:](i1[:])')
def pivots_to_modes(pivots):
    """
    Translate pivots into trend modes.
    Parameters
    ----------
    pivots : the result of calling peak_valley_pivots
    Returns
    -------
    A numpy array of trend modes. That is, between (VALLEY, PEAK] it is 1 and
    between (PEAK, VALLEY] it is -1.
    """
    modes = np.zeros(len(pivots), dtype='i1')
    modes[0] = pivots[0]
    mode = -modes[0]
    for t in range(1, len(pivots)):
        x = pivots[t]
        if x != 0:
            modes[t] = mode
            mode = -x
        else:
            modes[t] = mode
    return modes
```

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. Can you say anything about the function? Can you include the main ideas here, in case the link goes dead?

Comment: @gung Code added.